# What is the time complexity of finding the cube of a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, matrix-multiplication

I know that the complexity of multiplying two matrices directly AxB is O(n^3). So this holds good even when we are trying to find the square of a matrix, because that essentially means AxA.

What is the complexity when you are trying to find the cube of the matrix?

Comment: FYI, there are [more efficient method for matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is O(n<sup>3</sup>)

Why?

- You can calculate the cube with two matrix multiplications.
- Doing a matrix multiplication of square matrices does not change n.
- Doing two O(n<sup>3</sup>) operations in series is also O(n<sup>3</sup>).

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) for a formal definition.

Comment: Hey thanks! That's what I wanted to confirm, whether doing two O(n^3) operations in series is also O(n^3).

Comment: Yes, the formal definition given in Wikipedia makes that pretty clear.  Big O means that as n->Infinity, the time divided by the function goes to a constant.  So it just doubles the constant.